# Using active class in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using active class in my router link like this :

```html
<li class="list-group-item">
  <router-link :to="{name:'category'}" active-class="active">
    Category
  </router-link>
</li>
```

this code is working and the link is active but i want this link to be active on two router link i.e. on category and subcategory how can i achieve this result.

Comment: Is `subcategory` a child route of `category`?

Comment: @Phil: No it is not a child route

Comment: Try using [linkExactActiveClass](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#linkexactactiveclass) of vue router link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your `subcategory` route is *not* a child of `category`, you'll have to implement the logic yourself

```html
<router-link
  :to="{ name: 'category' }"
  active-class="active"
  :class="{
    active: $route.matched.some(({ name }) => name === 'subcategory')
  }"
>
  Category
</router-link>
```

This will add the `active` class if the route matches `category` (or any of its children) as well as `subcateory` (or any of its children).

[image: Edit icy-smoke-he1sd]